# Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor Unsupported object type tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, tensor

I have problem on converting my data to tensor.

x = data[['clean_title','images']]
type(x)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

My data has two features ;text and the output of vgg16 for images, I need to convert it to tensor so that I can fit my model on them but I get this error.

I'm not sure what to do.

tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor).

There is no null in my data.

I'm gonna fit my model on this after splitting. My model has two part one part for the text and one part for the image then fully connected plus FLN layers at the end.